# $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}x_n$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}x_n^3$ converges also?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}x_n$ converge. $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathbb R$
>
> Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}x_n^3$ converge too?

I tried to find some counter-examples but found none. I tried to prove this also, but I can't... I don't know even if it's true or not.

Comment: @user37238 I tried to find some counter-examples but found none. I tried to prove this also, but I can't... I don't know even if it's true or not... :/

Comment: this question is not as simple as it first looks like..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a= \exp(2 \pi i/3)$ (such that $1+a+a^2=0$ and $a^3=a^6=1$)

Take the series $$x_{3n} = \frac{1}{n^{1/3}},\quad x_{3n+1} = ax_{3n},\quad x_{3n+2}=a^2x_{3n}.$$

With such choice of $x$, the series $\sum_n x_n$ converges, but the series $\sum_n x_n^3$ does not.

**edit**

Choose real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $$a+b+c=0\\a^3+b^3+c^3>0.$$
For example, $a=-1$, $b=-2$, $c=3$. Then take

$$x_{3n} = \frac{a}{n^{1/3}},\quad x_{3n+1} = \frac{b}{n^{1/3}},\quad x_{3n+2}=\frac{c}{n^{1/3}}.$$

With such choice of $x$, the series $\sum_n x_n$ converges, but the series $\sum_n x_n^3$ does not.

Comment: without Complex numbers, just the Real numbers please..

Comment: @Stabilo Such information must appear in the question!

Comment: @user37238 sorry, edited

Comment: @Stabilo see edits for the case of real number series.

Comment: Apparently the counterexample (at least for the Reals) doesn't work. Both series are converge, using dirichlet's test...

Comment: You have another example maybe??

Comment: @Stabilo just notice that in my counterexample you can say that $$\sum_{k=3}^{3n+5} x_k^3 = (a^3+b^3+c^3)\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac 1j,$$ and the latter sum clearly diverges to infinity as $n\to\infty$. Write in more details how you apply the Dirichlet's test so we can find out where you have an error.

Comment: maybe I don't understand your notation. What $x_n$ looks like? 
$x_{1} = -2 , x_{2} = \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]2} , x_{3} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]3} , x_{4} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt[3]4} ...$?

Comment: @Stabilo No, the sequence goes like this: $$\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{1}},\frac{-2}{\sqrt[3]{1}},\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{1}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\frac{-2}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{3}},\frac{-2}{\sqrt[3]{3}},\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{3}},\quad etc.$$

Comment: My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, if the signs of the $x_n$ are not the same; here's a fairly typical counterexample.  Define the series $\sum_nx_n$ as follows. Its positive terms are $1/n^{1/3}$ for all natural numbers $n$, each of these terms occurring exactly once. Its negative terms are $-1/n^{4/3}$, each occurring exactly $n$ times, immediately after the corresponding positive term $1/n^{1/3}$.  In other words, the series consists of blocks of consecutive terms, where the $n$th black consists of $1/n^{1/3}$ followed by $n$ consecutive occurrences of $-1/n^{4/3}$. Notice that each block has sum $0$, from which it easily follows that the whole series converges to $0$.  Now consider what happens when you cube each term. The $n$th block of the new series consists of a positive term $1/n$ followed by $n$ consecutive negative terms $-1/n^4$.  The $n$ negative terms in the $n$th block add up to $-1/n^3$ which is far from cancelling the positive term $1/n$.  Indeed, except for the first block or two, the sum of the $n$th block will be positive and larger than $1/(2n)$.  Since the harmonic series diverges, this means that the series of cubes diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots$ also has blocks that have sum $0$, but does not converge to $0$...

Comment: @MichaelBiro I said "it easily follows", not that it follows without any further thought, or that it generalizes to arbitrary series with blocks summing to zero.  It does easily follow in the case at hand because the partial sums within any block are bounded by $1/n^{1/3}$, which converges to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Hint : justify that there exists $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ :

$$(x_n)^3\leq x_n $$

and conclude.

Comment: This would work only for positive series.

Comment: This is not always the case : if $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ then $(x_n)^3\ge x_n$

Comment: @stity only for odd $n$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, yes I had positive series in mind (+1) thanks for pointing this.